# iPhone: Which Method to Use to Rotate View Back to Portrait Orientation?

Tags: iphone, uikit, uiview, uiviewcontroller, rotation

I use...

```
-(void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:
```

... to adapt a view that has been rotated to landscape.

However, I don't know which method to use when the view needs to be rotated back to portrait.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the same method but include a test to see what the orientation change was.

```
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation{
    switch fromInterfaceOrientation {
        case UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait {
            //... handle roation from portrait
            break;
        }
        case  UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft {
            //... handle roation LandscapeLeft
            break;
        }
        //.. and so on
    }
}
```

However, configuring a view for its new orientation should be done in one of the rotation methods that begin with "will". The above method tells the view controller what the ***previous*** orientation was. It doesn't send what the current orientation is or will be. The "will" methods allow you adapt the view before the new orientation completes.

Answer (score 1):

> I use (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation to adapt view when rotation is enabled …

You're missing a colon. The method takes an argument, so it's `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:`.

`didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation` is another valid selector, but it names a completely different (and probably non-existent and never-called) method.

> … but, wich method or how to detect that iphone got back to vertical position in order to readapt view???

As near as I can make out from [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/), the same method does both jobs. The argument to the method is the old orientation, and `self.interfaceRotation` is the new rotation.

So, check one of those values (I'd use `self.interfaceRotation` if I were an iPhone programmer) to see which orientation you're in now, and update your view accordingly.